# Extra whitespace in number of questions on "tags" page

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, design, whitespace

If I open `/tags` on any site of Stack Exchange network (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/tags)  I see something like this:

> [image]

Note the whitespaces between "today" and the comma.

This is definitely a bug.

Comment: Free hand **black** circle?!

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Yeap, the weather here is really dull, didn't feel like using colors.

Comment: Well, it's hot weather here so red fits perfectly!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed as of the 2013.11.13.* build revs:

[image: moar zirclez]

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that there are white space before and after every link's text which is not required.

> [image]

Also a white space is already there after comma:

> [image]

So we need to remove those space before and after link's text.

Comment: Write a user script! ;)

Comment: aww, so many red lines. :)